# PHP: When an associative array is within a function, and the function is called more than once, does it create the array multiple times?

Tags: php, arrays, function

So I have a function called vendorGet() and it contains an array of vendor names and their logos. I call the vendorGet() function in another array and pass it a string argument to tell it which vendor to output from the array of vendors. Does doing this cause the PHP script to create this array every time the function is called, or does it create it once within the function and reference itself each time?

Hope that made sense. Let me know if there is anything I can clarify.
Here is some (shortened down and simplified) code as a reference,

```
// Vendor Fetcher
function vendorGet($data)
{
  $vendor = array(
    'foo' => array(
      'name' => 'Foo Products',
      'image' => (VENDOR_IMG . 'foo/foo-logo.png'),
    ),
    'bar' => array( // ABT
      'name' => 'Bar Inc.',
      'image' => (VENDOR_IMG . 'bar/bar-logo.png'),
    ),
  );

  return $vendor[$data];
}

// Array calling vendorGet() function
$catalogue = array(
  'chapter-1' => array(
    'vendors' => array(
      1 => vendorGet('foo'),
      2 => vendorGet('bar'),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php `PHP supports passing arguments by value (the default), ...` That means passing a large array will copy that array.

Comment: `$vendor` will be dropped each time `vendorGet()` returns.  The function will re-create `$vendor` each time it is called; only the return sub-array continues to exists between function calls.  To avoid this, put `vendorGet()` into a class with a constructor function that creates `$vendor[]`.  When you create an instance of the class, `$vendor[]` will exist and `$vendorGet()` can refer to it with each call.

Comment: @JuanTomas Ah okay, thank you for the advice!

Comment: `static  $vendor = array(...`  would only create it once.

Comment: @RyanVincent Cool, I'll try it out. Can you explain why that would happen, and if it is good or bad practice?

Comment: I don't see any issues at all. If the two functions are tested as blackboxes then the output is identical. The only difference is that one only assigns it once. As it is not returned by reference then the usual 'copy on write' rules apply if it is changed locally in some other context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, the array will be set up every time the function is called because you're defining it within the function

If you want to avoid this you can use a class

```
class vendor {

   public static $vendor = array(
       'foo' => array(
         'name' => 'Foo Products',
         'image' => (VENDOR_IMG . 'foo/foo-logo.png'),
       ),
       'bar' => array( // ABT
         'name' => 'Bar Inc.',
         'image' => (VENDOR_IMG . 'bar/bar-logo.png'),
       ),
    );


    public static function get($data) {
         return self::$vendor[$data];
    }
}
```

Comment: Good to know, thanks! I am still pretty new to OOP, but i will give this model a shot. Ill mark your answer as correct since you gave an example to go with your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The code you have written will re-create the array every single time the function is called.

You can create the array outside of this function and still have the function reference the array if it's within a class using "this" or you can pass in the array as a variable to the function.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a function to do this. Arrays allow you to access by key.

```
// Vendor Array
$vendor = array(
    'foo' => array(
        'name' => 'Foo Products',
        'image' => (VENDOR_IMG . 'foo/foo-logo.png'),
    ),
    'bar' => array( // ABT
        'name' => 'Bar Inc.',
        'image' => (VENDOR_IMG . 'bar/bar-logo.png'),
    ),
);

// Array getting vendor by key
$catalogue = array(
    'chapter-1' => array(
        'vendors' => array(
            1 => $vendor['foo'],
            2 => $vendor['bar'],
        ),
    ),
);
```

Arrays allow you to access a key and return its corresponding value. You can also can also pull deeper into that array like this:

```
echo $vendor['foo']['name'];
```

This will output:

```
Foo Products
```

Comment: I originally had it like this, except i dont want to be accessing via index because if the data inside an individual vendors' array changes, i will have to change the index calls one by one. By using a function, i can specify the vendors name alone. This is because i have a for loop that loops through the vendors' array and outputs it's information (name, image, link, etc).

Comment: @mcjordalini: Whether you reference you vendor as `$vendor['foo']` or `vendor::get('foo')`, you will still use the key and have to update the key every place it is used.

Comment: This is true, i think misinterpreted what you meant the first time reading. my apologies. I think i am still gunna wrap a class around the array and its methods like the others have been suggesting.

Comment: @mcjordalini : It all depends on your scope and how reusable you need this array and data to be. My answer is the simplest way. Machavity's answer is not wrong, just more complex. Use what suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify:

- PHP has exactly *two* scopes: "local" and "global."  Any variable declared outside of a function is "global."  Any variable declared within a function is "local," *unless* the `global` directive is used to say that it is, in fact, global.
- PHP fully supports *recursion:*  a function may (directly or indirectly) call itself. The local variables of each *active instance* of that function are private to that instance.
- Variables are normally passed into functions "by value," which means that a duplicate is made.
- If you have many related functions that need to share common data, consider making a `class`, with the functions being "methods" of that class. Now, they all have access to `$this`, which refers to the object-instance to which they belong. Notice also that properties (and methods) can be declared either `public` or `private`, which is an effective way to keep other parts of the code from seeing *(and therefore, possibly meddling with ...)* them.

Comment: I definitly am gunna be making a Vendor class. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it creates the array each time you call the function.

Performing a memory usage asserts it.

```
<?php 

function vendorGetArray()
{
  return array(
    'foo' => array(
      'name' => 'Foo Products',
      'image' => ( 'foo/foo-logo.png'),
    ),
    'bar' => array( // ABT
      'name' => 'Bar Inc.',
      'image' => ( 'bar/bar-logo.png'),
    ),
  );

}

function memoryUsage()
{
    echo "memory: ".(memory_get_peak_usage(false)/1024/1024)." MiB<br>";
}


$vendorArray = vendorGetArray();

// Array calling vendorGet() function
$catalogue = array(
  'chapter-1' => array(
    'vendors' => array(
      1 => $vendorArray['foo'],
      2 => $vendorArray['bar']
    ),
  ),
);

memoryUsage();

?>
```

The above code prints:

> memory: 0.231658935547 MiB

While your code

```
<?php

function vendorGet($data)
{
  $vendor = array(
    'foo' => array(
      'name' => 'Foo Products',
      'image' => ( 'foo/foo-logo.png'),
    ),
    'bar' => array( // ABT
      'name' => 'Bar Inc.',
      'image' => ( 'bar/bar-logo.png'),
    ),
  );

  return $vendor[$data];
}

function memoryUsage()
{
    echo "memory: ".(memory_get_peak_usage(false)/1024/1024)." MiB<br>";
}


// Array calling vendorGet() function
$catalogue = array(
  'chapter-1' => array(
    'vendors' => array(
      1 => vendorGet('foo'),
      2 => vendorGet('bar'),
    ),
  ),
);

memoryUsage();
```

would print:

> memory: 0.231948852539 MiB